# How to print a "complex" tring on Python 3.6

Tags: python, arrays, string

thank you for being here.

I'm trying to print a "tic - tac - toe" board using a vector, something like this

if my vector is

```
b = [0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 0]
```

the board will be

```
[   |   | x ]
[   | o |   ]
[   | x |   ]
```

another example, if my vector is

```
b = [0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 2]
```

the board will be

```
[   |   |   ]
[   | x | o ]
[   |   | x ]
```

It means that if b[i] = 0, the board in the position i will be an space, if b[i] = 1, the board in the position i will be "x" and if b[i] = 2, the board in the position i will be "o".

The "base" board is

```
[ 1 | 2 | 3 ]
[ 4 | 5 | 6 ]
[ 7 | 8 | 9 ]
```

I've tried with this code

```
def printboard(board):
    a = " "
    for i in range(0,8):
        if board[i] == 0:
            a = a + " "
        elif board[i] == 1:
            a = a + "x"
        elif board[i] == 2:
            a = a + "o"
    print( a[1] + "|" + a[2] + "|" + a[3]
          %"---+---|---"
          %a[4] + "|" + a[5] + "|" + a[6]
          %"---+---|---"
          %a[7] + "|" + a[8] + "|" + a[9])
    return 0

board=np.array([0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0]) 
printboard(board)
```

but it doesn't work.

I think my problem is with the "print", I don't know how to do it right, and it is neccesary that the elements of the board to be separated by "|", "-" and "+" just as I tried.

I really hope someone can help me. Thank you so much (y)

Comment: What does "tring" mean?

Comment: And what's a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted

```
def printboard(board):
    a = []
    for i in range(0,9):
        if board[i] == 0:
            a = a + ["   "]
        elif board[i] == 1:
            a = a + [" x "]
        elif board[i] == 2:
            a = a + [" o "]
    print( a[0] + '|' + a[1] + '|' + a[2]
          +'\n---|---|---'
          +'\n'+a[3] + "|" + a[4] + '|' + a[5]
          +"\n---|---|---"
          +'\n'+a[6] + '|' + a[7] + '|' + a[8])
    return 0

board=np.array([0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0]) 
printboard(board)
```

You missed a newline in every row. Also, `a` string has to be replaced with array

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
import more_itertools

def print_board(my_list):

    for x in more_itertools.sliced([' ' if x == 0 else 'x' if x == 1 else 'o' for x in my_list], 3):
        print('[ ' + ' | '.join(x) + ' ]')
```

---

```
>>> print_board([0,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,0])
```

---

```
[   |   | x ]
[   | o |   ]
[   | x |   ]
```

---

@**EDIT**: you like even longer lines? Sure, no problem:

```
print('\n'.join('[ ' + ' | '.join(x) + ' ]' for x in __import__('more_itertools').sliced([' ' if x == 0 else 'x' if x == 1 else 'o' for x in my_list], 3)))
```

Comment: Woah, the `more_itertools` package! Definitely gonna check it out, always wanted more itertools functions :P For that, deserves an upvote!

Comment: @abccd: check it out, definitely worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

Split the array into 3s and construct strings from each sub array by replacing 0, 1 and 2 with their respective characters:

```
def print_board(lst):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), 3):
        print('[ ' + ' | '.join([(' ', 'o', 'x')[x] for x in lst[i:i+3]]) + ' ]')

b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2]       
print_board(b)
```

---

```
[   |   |   ]
[   | x | o ]
[   |   | x ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` call is indeed rather messed up. The main issue seems to be that you're randomly using `%` some of the time and other times using `+`. Only `+` works for concatenating strings. The `%` operator can be used with strings, but it does a different sort of string formatting (which might be an option for this problem, but not the way you've set it up so far). You're also not including any newlines inside the strings you're printing, so you'll probably want to add those.

I think if you replace your `print` call with this one, it will work:

```
print(a[1] + "|" + a[2] + "|" + a[3]
      + "\n---+---+---\n"
      + a[4] + "|" + a[5] + "|" + a[6]
      + "\n---+---+---\n"
      + a[7] + "|" + a[8] + "|" + a[9])
```

You could also use some of the features of the `print` function to handle some parts of the output for you (such as the newlines. Instead of concatenating all the component strings to build a single output string, you'd pass separate pieces to `print` as separate arguments, and you'd add a `sep` keyword parameter at the end:

```
print(a[1] + "|" + a[2] + "|" + a[3],
      "---+---+---",
      a[4] + "|" + a[5] + "|" + a[6],
      "---+---+---",
      a[7] + "|" + a[8] + "|" + a[9],
      sep="\n")
```

Note that in both of these example, I fixed the horizontal line to use two `+`s rather than one `+` and one `|`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dictionary` to `map` symbols to values and then use `numpy` to convert list to N x N `matrix` as below.

```
import numpy as np
keymap = {0 : '|' , 1 : 'x', 2: 'o'}
b = [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0]
a = np.array([keymap[x] for x in b]).reshape((3,3,))

>>> for i in a:
    print('[ ' + '  '.join(i) + ' ]')


[ |  |  x ]
[ |  o  | ]
[ |  x  | ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interactive demonstration using zip and join.

```
>>> b = '0 0 1 0 2 0 0 1 0'.split(' ')
>>> c = [" xo"[int(e)] for e in b]
>>> d = ['[','|','|',']\n[','|','|',']\n[','|','|',']']
>>> print("".join(["".join(e) for e in zip(d, c+['\n'])]))
[ | |x]
[ |o| ]
[ |x| ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzBCsIwEETv@Yohl81iKVXPfkm6l7YRI7IJNQcV/z22UPHmYeANM7z8LJekx1oHnEAdOuyXHLARtfd8i8URiM24XLzFI1kftbjAgnOaERAVg5hpnclTQ@8t0uu/SmLyvJqsba8pqvNfCPwzv2J2U4Nx56lXEhbmWj8)